# C# linq group by

Tags: c#, linq

How do I count, group and sort the following list based on a persons money with linq?

```
        Person[] names = { new Person{ Name = "Harris", Money = 100 }, 
                                new Person{ Name = "David", Money = 100 },
                                new Person{Name = "Harris", Money = 150},
                                new Person{Name = "Mike", Money = 100},
                                new Person{Name = "Mike", Money = 30},
                                new Person{Name = "Mike", Money = 20} };
```

The result would return:

```
Harris 250 
Mike 150 
David 100
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from p in names
group p by p.Name into g
order by g.Key
select new { Name = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(o => o.Amount) }
```

Comment: nitpick: the order-by is contradicted by the sample output.

Comment: Also by sample data you should write: Amount = g.Sum(o => o.Money)

Answer (score 8):

```
 var personMoney = names.GroupBy(x=>x.Name)
                   .Select(x=>new {Name = x.Key, AllMoney = x.Sum(y=>y.Money)})
                   .OrderByDescending(x=>x.AllMoney).ToList();
```